# Configuração do htaccess para capturar todos os dados GET de uma query string

Tags: php, jquery, html, htaccess, querystring

eu reescrevi a regra da minha url da seguinte forma:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

No php eu obtenho os parâmetros de `$_GET['path']` e configuro o meu controlador, ação e parâmetros.

`$this->controlador`, `$this->acao` e `$this->parametros`

Se eu montar a url nesse formato dá tudo certo na minha aplicação:

```
http://www.example.com/controlador/acao/parametro1/parametro2/etc...
```

Sendo que eu preciso saber o que está vindo do form. Daí eu queria passar a query string como parâmetro.
Tipo:

```
http://www.example.com/controlador/acao/query_string
```

Onde `query_string = id=123&name=jose&dica=ok`

O problema é que a variável global `$_GET` está retornando o seguinte:

```
$_GET['path'] = "controlador/parametro/id=123"
$_GET['name'] = "jose"
$_GET['dica'] = "ok"
```

Teria como vir somente o `$_GET['path']` com a string completa.
Tipo:

```
$_GET['path'] = "controlador/parametro/id=123&name=jose&dica=ok"
```

Comment: Parceiro, ou trate no lado do cliente ou no servidor. Tratando-se de formulário, cada campo é um dado, se você não agrupar em run-time com javascript(em um único campo, tipo um input[type='hidden'], então arrume isso ao lado do servidor, recebendo os dados e agrupando em uma única variavel. Mas $_GET, dados de controle, visibilidade na URL para mim não parece nada seguro..

Comment: Ok pode não ser seguro para dados críticos. Mas, no caso da minha aplicação faz sentido ser assim. O problema é que se passar uma querystring via GET automaticamente no servidor é quebrada na global $_GET. Se eu mudar a querystring do lado do cliente funcionaria.

Comment: Tipo substituindo o "&" por "/": 

formdata =  $("#form").serialize();
formdata = formdata.replace(/[&]/g, "/");

O resultado seria 
"controlador/parametro/id=123/name=jose/dica=ok"

Eu não acho prático fazer isso no lado do cliente. Minha pergunta é se a querystring poderia ser reescrita por algum método nativo do JQuery ou tratada pelo RewriteRule no htaccess.